# Can't find file from getcachedir() even though success with FileIO

Tags: java, android

I am downloading a file via FTP and storing it locally and trying to get the Uri of the file. I use .getCacheDir() and File.createTempFile() for the file path. The FTP.retrieveFile() returns true saying the file was downloaded. However, The readBitmap() procedure returns null when trying to read the bitmap.

outputFile = /data/data/my.package.name/cache/b924df6f-4c0f-40c6-9c88-47dc021a02dc52132684.jpg, which does not exist on the phone or the SD card. I read in another thread that it is really stored at /sdcard/Android/data/yourapp/cache/. My app (folder named with package name) does not have a folder under that path, either on the phone or the SD card.

So I'm confused, if FTP (org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP) returns true where is the file?

Is /data/data/my.package.name/cache/b924df6f-4c0f-40c6-9c88-47dc021a02dc52132684.jpg a real path or not? If it is not, how can get the real path so I can convert it in to Uri?

Greg

```
OutputStream output;
String fileName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
File outputDir = MainActivity.this.getCacheDir(); 
File outputFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".jpg", outputDir);
output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

if (!mFtpClient.retrieveFile(d.ImageName, output)) {        
    Log.e("FTPDownload", String.valueOf(mFtpClient.getReplyCode()));
}                        
else {
    Bitmap imageBitmap;
    //readBitmap() returns null and throws an exception
    //I use readBitmap() when uploading to display the image before uploading
    //It works if there is a valid Uri passed in.
    imageBitmap = readBitmap(Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageData = null;
    imageData = baos.toByteArray();

    d.ImageData = imageData;

    output.close();
}
```

Comment: Well one minor thing is that Ftp does not close the stream.  Try closing it before you read it in as a Bitmap and that may help.

Comment: Yes, I do have output.close();, but after I try and read the file. Moving it up to above readBitmap() resolved the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes that is a real path. No need for an uri as it is already a real path.

Comment: You have to show the `readBitmap()` code of course.

Comment: The path you mentioned is internal private memory for your app. If you take a file explorer app that explorer cannot see it as it is private to your app.